# Cherry pick from local source

Tags: android, git

I am new to kernel building on android. I have a moto g. I used the cm source code and built a basic cm kernel. It booted. Now i want to cherrypick. I have cloned another repo. Now i want to cherry pick stuff into my kernel from that local source. I tried googling a lot but couldn't come up with a way. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here I would like to share an idea to solve your problem.

Push the branch (where your stuff exists) from one repository to another where you want to cherry-pick your stuff.

For example, your stuff exists in `kernel-1` repository on `branch-1` branch and you want to cherry-pick your stuff into `kernel-2` repository on `branch-2` branch.

Go to `kernel-1` repository.

```
$ cd $WORKSPACE/kernel-1
$ git checkout branch-1
$ git push $WORKSPACE/kernel-2 HEAD:refs/heads/branch-1
```

Now go to kernel-2 repository.

```
$ cd $WORKSPACE/kernel-2
```

And you will find `branch-1` here. So you can cherry-pick your stuff.

Comment: can you explain with the commands too? this seems quite confusing. I have a folder kernel(mine) and optimus(to be cherrypicked). what do i do now?

Comment: Hi Sorry for late response.
I am also confused that what command you are expecting.
Even though from my understanding, I think you are expecting like below. (please see my another answer)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have two folder.
1. kernel (change will be cherry-picked into here)
2. optimus (change will be cherry-picked from here)

Go to optimus folder and craete a branch say, `my-local-stuff` from your stuff.
`$ cd optimus
$ git checkout -b my-local-stuff <your stuff>
$ git push <absolute path of kernel folder> HEAD:refs/heads/my-local-stuff`

Now go to kernel folder and you will find `my-local-stuff` branch.

`$ cd kernel
$ git checkout my-local-stuff
$ git log
<you can see the commits which you have created into optimus folder>`

Now cherry-pick the commit whatever you need into whichever branches.

Please let me know if more explanation is needed.

Comment: will check and let u know!